# Can I render different passes into different folder automatically?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, render-passes

I have a file output node rendering different passes into a single folder (circled in pink).
I have set up folders for different passes (circled in yellow) and I want to set blender to automatically render the different passes into different folders because as of right now, blender renders all of the passes into a single folder (circled in teal). Is there a way to automatically render different passes into different select folders?

P.S. I believe you can just use several different file output nodes, but it wouldn't be as convenient as using one so...

[image]

Comment: Can't you just use multiple File Output nodes in the Compositor?

Comment: I think so, but that wouldn't be as convenient as using one. I'll edit my question to include that :)

Comment: Like a one click multiple folders, no there is no option like that. Easiest way is multiple file outputs; another option, multiple scenes, every scene to render a different pass to a different output, last option (that i hear of) to automate the file paths could be Python, but you need to find a script/add-on or write one

Comment: Don't use png, it is a garbage format to store render passes. Just use OpenEXR multilayer anD save whatever passes you need in a single file.

Comment: Thanks yep! that's what I'm doing!